# Optimization for Binary Search Tree 'remove' function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I just finished my first binary search tree `remove` function and it is in major need of optimization. I have spent a lot of time on this and this was the best I could manage. Is there a easier way to do this? Does anyone have any suggestions for optimization? To me, it just seems like it will necessarily be massive code.

For starters...

***My Binary Search Tree...***

```
function BST() {
    this.root = null;
}
```

***My 'remove' function...***

```
BST.prototype.remove = function(data) {
    if(this.root.data === data){
        var curr = this.root.left;
        while(true){
            if(curr.right.left === null && curr.right.right === null){
                this.root.data = curr.right.data;
                curr.right = null;
                break;
            }
            curr = curr.right;
        }
    }

    var curr = this.root;
    var found_data = this.find(data);
    if(found_data.left !== null && found_data.right !== null){
        var runner = found_data.right;
        var runner_prev = found_data;
        while(true){
            if(runner.left === null && runner.right === null){
                found_data.data = runner.data;
                if(runner_prev.left === runner){
                    runner_prev.left = null;
                }else{
                    runner_prev.right = null;
                }
                break;
            }
            runner_prev = runner;
            runner = runner.left;
        }
    }else if(found_data.left === null || found_data.right === null){
        var prev = this.prev(found_data.data);
        if(prev.right === found_data){
            if(found_data.left){
                prev.right = found_data.left;
            }else{
                prev.right = found_data.right;
            }
        }else{
            if(found_data.left){
                prev.left = found_data.left;
            }else{
                prev.left = found_data.right;
            }
        }
    }else{
        var prev = this.prev(found_data.data);
        if(prev.left === found_data){
            prev.left = null;
        }else{
            prev.right = null;
        }
    }

};
```

You will notice that I use supporting functions within my `remove()` function,  such as `prev()` and `find()` They are apart of my overarching `BST()` function and can be used anywhere within is by prefacing it using `this.`.

***Supporting functions I use within `remove()` (`prev()` and `find()`)***

```
BST.prototype.find = function(data) {
    if(this.root === null){
        return 'wrong';
    }

    var curr = this.root;
    while(true){
        if(data > curr.data){
            curr = curr.right;
        }else if(data < curr.data){
            curr = curr.left;
        }else{
            if(curr.data enter code here=== data){
                return curr;
            }else{
                return 'not here player'
            }
        }
    }
}

BST.prototype.prev = function(data){
    if(this.root === null){
        return false;
    }
    var prev = this.root;
    var curr = this.root;
    while(true){
        if(curr.left === null && curr.right === null){
            return prev;
        }
        if(data < curr.data){
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.left;
        }else if(data > curr.data){
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.right;
        }else{
            return prev;
        }
    }
}
```

This algorithm absolutely works, but as you can imagine, this is not the type of monster you would want to be answering a whiteboard interview question with.

Comment: Is the absence of recursion intentional? Not using recursion on an recursive data structure is bound to be clunky. You should also look into BST rotations, which preserve order but let you move nodes around easily (you can use them to implement balancing too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be more efficient if you either:

1. Combine `prev()` and `find()` by returning both the previous node and the found node from `find()`
2. Give each node a parent pointer, and just follow it to find `prev`